# How to reconciliate fear of some people mentioned in th Quran with its claim?

Tags: quran, tafseer

In many places Quran talks about fear of men:

1. When Moses went out of that city
2. When Abrahim met his angle guests
3. When Muhammad asked his cave companion to not be frightened (which means he was fearful)

However, Quran in many places claims that good people **la khawfun alayhim** (no fear would be upon them).

I'm interested in Quran-only analysis (lingual and semantic cross-reference) to  reconciliate these seemingly inconsistencies.

Comment: A first view obvious understanding is that one is about Jannah, and the three are all stories of the world.

Comment: It would be good to know the qur'an verses you are referring to. 1. could be ([28:8](https://legacy.quran.com/28/18)) or more likely ([28:21](https://legacy.quran.com/28/21), 2. should be ([11:70](https://legacy.quran.com/11/70)), 3. should be ([9:40](https://legacy.quran.com/9/40)). This would linguistically be a cocktail because you have the adjective خائف, the verb خاف and the verb حزن which may express a fear but rather refers to sadness and grief. As for the expression you want to compare with it clearly say by Allah meaning in the hearafter and it uses the noun الخوف.

Comment: Example 3 hardly fits here because حزن is neither in the context nor usually expressing fear. It expresses a grief, sadness or sorrow in first place. However it would fit if you wanted to compare it with the quranic expression which was repeated many times in surat al-Baqara and also elsewhere "لاخوف عليهم ولاهم يحزنون " nevertheless it is clear that a comparision hardly holds, as in the hearafter everthing is decided so either you have what one may call ethernal joy or not.

Answer (score 1):

Allah says:

> And We send not the messengers except as bringers of good tidings and warners. So whoever believes and reforms - there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve. (6:48)

There are many other similar verses.

Someone could interpret this as meaning the good believers will never feel fear or grief either in this world or the next.

But, this interpretation would be refuted by the fact that even the prophets are known to fear some things as mentioned by Allah.

So, what we are left with is that it either refers to a specific fear or refers to a specific time.

If specific fear, it might refer to the fear that Allah will be unjust with them.

If specific time (and this is by far the most supported by the rest of the Quran and the mufassiroon), this refers to when they enter Paradise.

The reason I say it is most supported is because plenty of other verses elaborate that this fear is about in Paradise.

For example, Allah says:

> [Allah will say], "Are these the ones whom you [inhabitants of Hell] swore that Allah would never offer them mercy? Enter Paradise, [O People of the Elevations]. No fear will there be concerning you, nor will you grieve." (7:49)

In this verse, Allah shows that "No fear and no grief" is said to the people of Paradise when they are entering it.

And Allah says:

> [To whom Allah will say], "O My servants, no fear will there be concerning you this Day, nor will you grieve, (43:68)

In this verse, Allah says there will be no fear "this Day," implying it existed before.

In other verses, this phrase of "no fear" is mentioned after Allah mentions the reward. Like when Allah says:

> Yes [on the contrary], whoever submits his face in Islam to Allah while being a doer of good will have his reward with his Lord. And no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve. (2:112)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had written the address of the verses in your question.
Thanks also for your explanation in the last line. A friendly check is more useful than a hostile check.
It is better not to compare the third case with prophets such as Moses and Abraham.

Divine prophets, apart from their prophetic status, are human beings by the nature of human beings, like other people, and just as they eat, drink, get sick, etc., they are afraid of unexpected events like others, and they defend their lives against accidents and dangers. And this does not contradict the dignity of their prophecy.
These kinds of fears are not something that contradicts the status of prophethood, and the issue of the fears of Moses and Abraham (pbuh) is in the same direction. But what the prophets are not afraid of is the fear of doing their duty, in everything that is related to their mission. They have no fear of being killed, losing their property and lives, losing their wives and children, and if they are afraid, they are afraid that they will not be able to succeed in their mission.
The divine saints are full of the fear of God; Fear of not performing duties and responsibilities, and sorrow over what has been lost from their successes, that this fear and sorrow has a spiritual aspect and is the cause of the evolution of human existence and his progress.

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa80796

Comment: Moses tells Allah that "I fear that they kill me". Please don't write your personal interpretation as an answer. It's also a sin. "Who is more wongdoer than the one who attributes a lie to Allah". Your answer contradicts the clear text of the Quran.